# Ajax request in ASP Mvc

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, json, asp.net-mvc-4

I am new in Mvc jason I have following ajax function the function is working fine and sending data to server action and the server also returning success or failure but the problem is the JSON data is displayed in new page like

{"Success":true}

here is my ajax function

```
$('#save').click(function () {
    var CourseID = $('.form-control span1').val();
    var Type = $('.form-control span2').val();
    var id =@Model.UserId
         $.ajax({
             url: '@Url.Action("AdminUser/Edit")',
             type: 'POST',
             data: { id: '@Model.UserId', CourseID: CourseID, Type: Type },
             Success: function (response) {
                 if (response.Success) {
                     alert("done");
                 }
                 else {
                     alert("Errror");
                 }

             }
         });



});
```

And here is my controller

```
      [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Edit(int id, string CourseID, string type)
    {
        KBS_Virtual_TrainingEntities db = new KBS_Virtual_TrainingEntities();
        var sc = (from course in db.CourseSubscriptions.ToList()
                  where course.Cours.ID.ToString() == CourseID && course.SubscriptionsType.ID.ToString() == type
                  select course).SingleOrDefault();
        UserSubscription new_sub = new UserSubscription();

        CourseSubscription sub_course = (CourseSubscription)sc;
        if (sub_course != null)
        {

            new_sub.CourseSubscription = sub_course;
            new_sub.CourseSubscriptionID = sub_course.ID;
            new_sub.StartedDate = DateTime.Now;
            new_sub.UserID = id;
            db.UserSubscriptions.Add(new_sub);
            db.SaveChanges();


            return Json(new { Success = true });
        }

         return Json(new{Success = false});
    }
```

Comment: Can you explain what you want to do with the result.

Comment: I just want to show that if the request was saved in the DB or not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this :

```
$('#save').click(function () {
var CourseID = $('.form-control span1').val();
var Type = $('.form-control span2').val();
var id =@Model.UserId
     $.ajax({
         url: '@Url.Action("AdminUser/Edit")',
         type: 'POST',
         data: { id: '@Model.UserId', CourseID: CourseID, Type: Type },
         Success: function (response) {
             if (response.Success) {
                 alert("done");
             }
             else {
                 alert("Errror");
             }
             return false;
         }
     });
```

});

return false will stop the redirection of the page and 
add script bundle ~/bundles/jqueryval

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the `return Json(new { Success = true });` into

> `return Json(new { });`

How about triggering the false instead and make it true by default?